# django.http.HttpResponse does not deal unicode properly

Tags: django, unicode, utf-8, django-views

following Tutorial 3, I have written this trivial **views.py**:

```
# coding = UTF-8
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse( u"Seznam kontaktů" )
```

I tried also other tricks, such as using `django.utils.encoding.smart_unicode(...)`, the `u"%s" % ...` trick, etc.

Whatever I try, I always get "*Non-ASCII character*" error:

```
SyntaxError at /kontakty/

Non-ASCII character '\xc5' in file C:\Users\JindrichVavruska\eclipse\workspace\ars\src\ars_site\party\views.py 
on line 5, but no encoding declared; 
see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (views.py, line 5)
```

It is even more mysterious because I used a lot of national character strings in other files, such as **models.py**, e.g. `text = models.CharField( u"Všechen text", max_length = 150)`, and there was absolutely no problem at all.

I found other answers on this site irrelevant, the suggested changes make no difference in my views.py

Jindra

Comment: Oh, yes, and there is `DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'` line in my **settings.py**. And, yes, I restarted the dev server couple of times when trying... ;-)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django or HttpResponse.

Comment: well, since it works fine with `# coding = UTF-8` and *u"..."* in all other modules and localized strings, I cannot see what else is different except taking HttpResponse into play. :(

Answer (score 2):

It should be `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` not `UTF-8`. See [PEP-263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for more details.  You should also save the file as UTF-8. Check your editor's settings.

Comment: Well, I simply cannot believe you, because `UTF-8` works in **models.py** in the same environment, same site, same application. And the reason why I have been writing UTF-8 in all my scripts is precisely because it was written so in documentation and because utf-8 did **not** work.

Comment: Well, you don't have to believe me, but that's what the error is telling you. Are you saving the files as UTF-8? Or just declaring the encoding but saving them as something else?